# copy files in local folder to gcs with renaming

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform

I wrote the following script whose aim is to copy files in a given path under a specified folder in gcs :

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -u

SOURCE=$1
CI_PROJECT_DIR="/home/user/project-ingestion"
DICT_PATH="${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/src/main/resources/dictionaries/$SOURCE"
DICT_BUCKETS="dict-bucket"

dictionaries="dictionaries"
DATE=`date '+%Y_%m_%d'`
for dictionary in $DICT_PATH/*.json; do
    FOLDER=${dictionary//+(*\/|.*)}
    TARGET="gs://$DICT_BUCKETS/$dictionaries/$SOURCE/$FOLDER/$FOLDER'_'$DATE.json"
    gsutil cp $dictionary  $TARGET
done
```

so if I have my `json` files under,

```
/home/user/project-ingestion/src/main/resources/dictionaries/source/factories.json
```

I want to copy it to,

```
gs://dict-bucket/factories/factories_2019_05_04.json
```

the script I wrote copy the whole dictionary tree to the given target. Any idea how to fix this please

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: ls in  gs://dict-bucket/factories gives this //home/user/project-ingestion/src/main/resources/dictionaries/source/factories.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the problem lies in following lines,

```
# parent path of $dictionary is not truncated
FOLDER=${dictionary//+(*\/|.*)}

# TARGET will contain single quotes
TARGET="gs://$DICT_BUCKETS/$dictionaries/$SOURCE/$FOLDER/$FOLDER'_'$DATE.json"
```

I'm not sure how exactly you are going to build the target path, but following might help (inside for loop block).

```
filename=$(basename $dictionary)    # e.g. factories.json
file_prefix=${filename%%.*}         # e.g. factories (remove everything after first period)
TARGET="gs://fixed_path/${file_prefix}/${file_prefix}_${DATE}.json" # change this as per your need
```